# SSIS Derived Columns Divide By Zero

Tags: ssis

dFuelCharge is mostly zero

How do I bypass the error when dividing by zero?

Expression

```
(dFuelCharge / (dShipCharge + dAccCharge))
```

makes a new column `dFuelRate`

Comment: You won't get a divide by 0 error if dFuelCharge is 0?

Comment: You are not dividing by dFuelCharge in your expression. Also, what do you expect to happen if dFuelCharge is zero?. Do you want the new column to be zero?. Be more specific

Comment: first you're not dividing by zero, second what to do depends on you, you can try_catch or if_else or other things

Comment: Yes i would want it to be Zero. This is in a Derived Column Transformation btw.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NULLIF operator and default it to 0 in case you get a divide by zero issue.

Comment: Does 2008R2 have NUFFIF? I do not see this and it reds out.

Answer (score 1):

No value of `dFuelCharge` will cause a divide by zero error.

What you need to do is determine what *should* the result be when `dShipCharge + dAccCharge` is zero?

- Is the fuel rate just fuel charge?

You're likely going to need to use the ternary operator, `?:` Read that as `Some test`, `true expression`, `else expression`.

```
(
    dFuelCharge 
    / 
    (
        (dShipCharge + dAccCharge) == 0
        ? 1.0 
        : (dShipCharge + dAccCharge)
    )
)
```

I split the expression into multiple lines for clarity but you can see the complete expression is fuel charge divided by: 1 if the sum of ship and acc charge are zero; otherwise, divide by the sum of ship and acc charges.

Do note that I have used `1.0` which results in floating point division (has a remainder). If you wanted integer based division (truncates decimal value) make that `1`

- Is the fuel rate unknown?

It could be that they don't want to record a rate when no ship and/or acc charges were provided. It's bad data so leave it null. This approach, as @rvphx pointed out, uses the `NULLIF(a, b)` operator. Read it as `if a matches b, return null. Otherwise, return a`

```
(dFuelCharge / NULLIF((dShipCharge + dAccCharge),0)
```

Comment: Sometimes dFuelRate should be Zero. I tried the NULLIF and it gives errors. Is NULLIF somthing that can be used in Derived Column Transformation?